# .Net Core - Are dependencies resolved on assembly loading?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-assembly

Imagine that in your library A, you declared a dependency to library B that you will never use.

If you try to dynamic load A and B is not around, will your application crash? or, as long as the methods that you call don't try to reach code on B you're in the clear?

Comment: Dependencies are resolved by the CLR when the just-in-time compiler needs an assembly.  So no.  "Never use" is not often judged correctly btw.  But you'll find out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on what you mean by "never use."

1. The code used to compile Library A never uses any API that is defined by library B.
2. The code in Library A uses API that is defined by Library B, but the code path in which that API is used is never called at runtime.

In case 1, the compiler will trim the unused references when it produces libraryA.dll. You don't need libraryB.dll and the runtime won't try to load it.

In case 2, you might be ok, but there are no guarantees. For example, if you had a class that references libraryB, even it that reference is from a method you never call, the runtime may still try to load libraryB.dll. You can sometimes cleverly structure code to avoid this load, but you're playing with fire. It is best to have libraryB available.

Comment: mine is the 2nd case... and thats what im planning to do: force the developers to declare a public method that returns a list of dependencies that should be loaded in runtime...

Comment: By the way, you can get a list of all possible reference assemblies by reading the reference table from the .dll file directly. See System.Reflection.Metadata. For example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.metadata.metadatareader?view=netcore-2.0

Comment: you're a genius! tks a lot!